Как при повторном вызове функции не вызвать внутренную функцию в С#?
Есть функция
  private void checkAndLoad()
 {


     string GenerateOrderNumber()
     {
         const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
         var random = new Random();
         return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
           .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
     }

     string orderNumber = GenerateOrderNumber();




     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderNumber))
     {


         string QueryGetItogPrice1 = $"select ({Numeric.Value} * price) as itog_cena from titles where title = '{TitlesList.Text}'";

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryGetItogPrice1, sqlConn);

         string summa = $"{cmd.ExecuteScalar():F2}";


         string QueryGetPrice = $"SELECT COALESCE(price, 0) AS ytd_sales FROM titles where title = '{TitlesList.Text}'";

         SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(QueryGetPrice, sqlConn);

         string price = $"{cmd3.ExecuteScalar():F2}";






         DataTable table = new DataTable();
         table.Columns.Add("№ Заказа", typeof(string));
         table.Columns.Add("Магазин", typeof(string));
         table.Columns.Add("Издания", typeof(string));
         table.Columns.Add("Кол-во", typeof(string));
         table.Columns.Add("Услове оплаты", typeof(string));
         table.Columns.Add("Цена", typeof(string));
         table.Columns.Add("Сумма", typeof(string));




         table.Rows.Add($"{orderNumber}", $"{StoresList.Text}", $"{TitlesList.Text}", Numeric.Value, Terms.Text, price, summa);


         DataGridView1.DataSource = table;
     }

 }

Нужно что бы при повторном вызове функции checkAndLoad() не вызывалась внутреняя функция GenerateOrderNumber().

Советую вам разделить код на отдельные кусочки, а не мешать все в одном, ибо сейчас у вас один метод отвечает за генерацию строки (почему метод внутри метода..?), формирование SQL запроса, работу с базой, формирования нужного вида для UI, вывод данных в UI. Как видите, 5 совершенно разных ответственностей у вас выполняется в одном месте, ну и именно это и приводит к проблеме, что указана в вопросе, ибо генерация уникального значения должна происходить например, при создании объекта (допустим класс и его конструктор), но не при "проверке" и "загрузке". Познайте азы ООП.

@EvgeniyZ просто нужно быстроенько сделать приложение, а ООП еще не знаю.

Вы учитесь, так учитесь изначально правильно, ведь понимаете, что "времени нет" - это отмаза... Прочитать про основы ООП займет от силы минут 5, понять их, минут 30, применить на практике для новичка, ну.. час.  Вам ведь не предлагают что-то сложное, наоборот, максимально простое, что облегчит вам лично жизнь. Но дело конечно ваше, я просто акцентирую внимание на то, из-за чего у вас вообще такой вопрос появился.

@EvgeniyZ понял учту!

@EvgeniyZ начиная с следующих проектов на C# )

Сделать полем например
private string orderNumber = null;
private readonly Random rnd = new Random(); 

private string GenerateOrderNumber()
{
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
        .Select(s => s[rnd.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}

private void checkAndLoad()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderNumber))
    {
        orderNumber = GenerateOrderNumber();
    }

    string QueryGetItogPrice1 = $"select ({Numeric.Value} * price) as itog_cena from titles where title = '{TitlesList.Text}'";
    // ... остальной код
}


вы изменли функцию GenerateOrderNumber  В этой строке .Select(s => s[Random.Shared.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray()); У Random нет Shared. Это от версии .Net зависит ?

@AslanPAPA да, зависит. Если используете устаревший фреймворк 4.x, то её нет. В любом случае, рандом не надо создавать на каждый вызов метода, в старом дотнете он генерит в таком случае всегда одно и то же.

всмысле ? А как тогда какой хороший способ генерации до 8 символов из этих символов "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

@AslanPAPA я поправил код. Рандом создаём один раз и далее не пересоздаём.

Спасибо помогли!
